# Wikidata property statement and property direct

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

I'm trying to retrieve entities as well as their properties that relate to Golden Gate Bridge. I used this query (https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fp2%20%3Fs%0AWHERE%0A%7B%0A%20%20%09%3Fs%20%3Fp2%20wd%3AQ44440%20.%0A%7D):

```
SELECT ?p2 ?s
WHERE
{
    ?s ?p2 wd:Q44440 .
}
```

But I noticed that in the result, property "p:statement/P800" and property "wdt:P800" actually point to the same thing. They have the same id. I'm wondering why it returns both. What is their difference? How do I just get one?

I use DBpedia a lot, so I'm not familiar with they uri schemes in Wikidata, it's quite confusing.

Comment: I don't have a full answer for you, but they are not actually the same property (even though you end up on the same page when clicking the link). `p:statement/P800` expands to `http://www.wikidata.org/prop/statement/P800`, while `wdt:P800` expands to `http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/P800`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it has something to do with the option to do reification on the statements itself, at least that's what I understand from the documentation here: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Glossary#Claims_and_statements That's why they use multiple namespace for the same property. You can see it better if you change your query to

```
SELECT ?s ?p
WHERE
{
    ?s ?p wd:Q44440 .
    ?p a owl:ObjectProperty
}
```

It returns, among others,

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
|                              s                              |        p         |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
| wd:Q16803333                                                | wdt:P301         |
| wd:Q261174                                                  | wdt:P800         |
| wd:Q950029                                                  | wdt:P921         |
| wd:statement/Q16803333-12EFD280-98AF-4CA1-BEA3-5C142674827D | p:statement/P301 |
| wd:statement/Q261174-4B53E291-A47B-48E3-AE28-7FDE75849E28   | p:statement/P800 |
| wd:statement/Q950029-fd9f357a-45ff-403a-86ba-b462acb2ffbd   | p:statement/P921 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
```

In that case you can see that the subjects also have a different namespace with `statement` as keyword. And about those statements you could make statements as well, called reification.

Comment: so can I put it this way that if I don't care about reification or a statement about a statement, I can just use items of namespace wd and properties of namespace wdt?

Comment: also why do I need to add "?p a owl:ObjectProperty" to get the results displayed into a more readable table?

Comment: I think you could do it that way, but to be honest I'm not a Wikidata expert. I'd suggest to ask at the Wikidata community for clarification, maybe via mailing list.

Comment: btw, is there a way to get the labels of the properties? For example if I use `SELECT ?s ?sLabel ?p ?pLabel
WHERE
{
 ?s ?p wd:Q44440 .
   ?p a owl:ObjectProperty .
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
     bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
 }
}` I only get the urls to the properties. For property P800, the label should be "notable work"

Comment: According to your 2nd comment: This was just to get rid of the triples with `schema:about` property (which is just an `rdf:Property` in the schema.org ontology. In that case is was easier to show that the subjects are also separate resources for statements.

Comment: Hm, good question: the query `SELECT ?s ?p ?p2 ?o2 WHERE {?s ?p wd:Q44440 .?p ?p2 ?o2}` to get all information about the properties as well returned just the `rdf:type` statements. Maybe those labels are in a different graph which is not the default graph in the web interface.

Comment: hmm, I figured I can get all the information about a property using name space `http://www.wikidata.org/entity/` `PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
SELECT * WHERE {wd:P800 ?p ?o}`, this is so cumbersome. I just want to get all property labels and subject labels in one query